# Is the function $f: (\mathbb{R} - \{0\})\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ surjective?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inverse-function

> Is the function $f: (\mathbb{R} - \{0\})\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ surjective?

My notes say that it isn't but I don't see why. The codomain is all real numbers, and if I plug in every single $x$ in the domain, it is possible to map to all the real numbers, so the range equals to codomain?

Comment: If it were surjective there would be an $x\ne 0$ so that $f(x) = 0$.  Is there such an $x$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x)=0$ has no solutions. In fact if $\frac{1}{x}=f(x)=0$, since $x\neq 0$, then $1=0\cdot x=0$.

Therefore it is not surjective.

Comment: Would it make sense if the function was ever defined to be $f:(\mathbb{R}-\{0\} + \{\infty\})\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ instead?

Comment: @similarityinvariance1 Yes, defining $f(\infty)=0$, or if $f:(\mathbb{R}-\{0\})\rightarrow (\mathbb{R}-\{0\})$

Comment: I see; for the first definition, is it important to add another to the function definition as $f(\infty = 0)$? Since it seems that we are just taking the limit if I just added $\{\infty\}$ to the domain

Comment: @similarityinvariance1: You could define it as $f(0)=0$ to get a surjection.

Comment: @Peyton: $\infty$ is not a Real number.

Comment: @gary And $0$ is not an element of $\mathbb{R}-\{0\}$. So, your $f(0)=0$ is as meaningful as $f(\infty)=0$. Actually, $f(\infty)=0$, adding the observation that the OP made is much more useful than $f(0)=0$ since you get beautiful analytic function.

Comment: @Peyton: I was referring to an extension when defining it on the whole of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @gary I know perfectly well what you are referring to. That is why I am explaining to you why your "$\infty$ is not a Real number" is pretty pointless. By the way, what makes you think that $(\mathbb{R}-\{0\})\cup\{\infty\}$ is not just $\mathbb{R}$ too. It looks to me the same.

Comment: @Peyton: Since $\infty$ is not part of $\mathbb R$ (Standard Real numbers) then $\mathbb R-\{0\} \cup \infty$ cannot equal the Reals. If $x \notin A$ then $x \cup A \neq A$. At least not equal as sets.

Comment: @gary Well, talk to you later, when you learn the math that you still need to learn.

Comment: @Peyton: Given your belief that " They seem equal to me"  is a Mathematical argument, then you are not ready to leave home.

Comment: @gary They are topologically the same, they are analytically the same.

Comment: @Peyton: you need to define the meaning of the expression and the properties of $\infty$, which you have not done. And I don't know what you mean by "equal analytically". If you amswer disrespectfully, I am done with you and not replying.

Comment: @gary Please, be done with me. And in the time you get away study what you need to study to understand this.

Comment: @Peyton: Using fancy terms you don't understand like "Analytically the same" does not impress me. Maybe a ged would be a good idea.

Comment: @Peyton: Ok, I understood what you said, but insulting others is not right. You could have explained more clearly. I don't think I insulted you, so you have no right to insult me.

Comment: Play nice, children.

Answer (score 1):

It has been answered that $f$ is not a surjection as there is no $x$ so that $f(x) = 0$.

A discussion in the comments then arose about how to change the domain and/or range so that $f(x) = 1/x$ is surjective.  This post will address that.

The easiest way to do that would be to modify the range from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R \setminus \{0\}$ so $f:\mathbb R \setminus \{0\}\rightarrow \mathbb R \setminus \{0\}$.  This is surjective as for any $z \in \mathbb R \setminus \{0\}$ we have $\frac 1z$ in domain and $f(\frac 1z)= z$.

To extend the *domain* so that $f:D \rightarrow \mathbb R $ and $f(x) = \frac 1x; x \in \mathbb R \subset X$ we simply need to add any element to the domain and define $f$ or that element is equal to $0$.

So, believe, it or not, the following **is** perfectly valid math:

Let $X = [\mathbb R \setminus \{0\}] \cup \{babar,\ the\ elephant\}$ and let $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be defined as $f(x) = \frac 1x$ if $x \in \mathbb R\setminus \{0\}$ and $f(babar,\ the\ elephant) = 0$.

Then $f$ is surjective.  (No, I'm not kidding.)

You could also do:

Define the extended reals to include $\infty, -\infty$ and include the identities $\frac 1{\infty} = \frac 1{-\infty} = 0$, and let $X = [\mathbb R \setminus \{0\}] \cup \{\infty\}$ then $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb R$ as $f(x) = \frac 1x$ is surjective.

Perhaps the most elegant is simply to define $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ as $f(0) = 0$ and $f(x) = \frac 1x$ for all $x \ne 0$.

But those last three are actually exactly the same.  To extend the range to include $0$, we need to add an element $k$ to the domain and define $f(k) =0$.  It does not matter whether $k$ is $\infty$, $0$, or $babar,\ the \ elephant$.

Comment: Of course you can, but I would think at this level of question, one is thinking of extending into the Reals and avoiding using $\infty$.

Comment: It might say something about me that it didn't really occur to me one was thinking of extending the domain and range both to the reals.  Of course one should wonder why we are doing any of this.  There's nothing wrong with claiming f simply isn't surjective and leaving it at that.

Comment: I think the OP asked  in the commentsif the function could be extended, but did not clarify into what.

Answer (score 1):

Another good thing to do here would be to draw a sketch of the graph of $\frac{1}{x}$ and look at the values it takes on.